# Approximation for rotational drag on a box?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag

The [drag equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation) gives us an approximation for the drag on an object caused by its velocity in a fluid:

$F = \frac{1}{2} \rho A v^2 C_d$

Is there any similar approximation for the *rotational* drag on an object caused by its angular velocity? I am particularly concerned with boxes (rectangular prisms), but would also be interested in a more general approximation, if one is available. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if analysis with dimensionless numbers might help set up some useful relation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity#Buckingham_.CF.80_theorem

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea. I've been thinking about treating each exposed *face* of the box as it's own shape, and computing forces that way. Then it would just come down computing the drag force (linear and rotational) of 6 planes. I'd still need to work out an approximation for the rotational drag of a plane though...